# Closing a dialog created by JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an options dialog using `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)`;

For the options parameter I am passing an array of JButtons each with its own `ActionListener`.

One of these buttons is responsible for closing the dialog.  My question is: what code do I place in the close button's event handler to close the option dialog?

A point that may make a difference: the class responsible for showing this dialog is a singleton and, as such, the method responsible for displaying the dialog is *static*.  Therefore, calling `javax.swing.JInternalFrame.doDefaultCloseAction();` does not work "from a static context".

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
final JButton btn = new JButton("Close");

btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(btn);

    if (w != null) {
      w.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Probably the dirtiest way I have seen to close a JOptionPane, but thanks because you just saved my butt

Comment: @Smac89: Yes it's fairly disgusting.  Obviously if you subclass JDialog and set up the ActionListener within the subclass at least you can avoid the call to SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor().

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane is closed by calling its setValue method

(Speaking of dirty side effects)