# How to dispose JOptionPane after x seconds

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, joptionpane

So I have a code like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < totalNumPlayers; i++) {

                runTimer(30, myTextArea);

                players.get(i).bet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(players.get(i).name + ", please enter your bet: ");

            }
```

I need to auto-submit JOptionPane (with a default int value) after the timer expires.

Code of my timer:

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule((Callable) () -> {

        for (int j = 1; j <= duration; j++) {

            myTextArea.replaceRange("\n" + String.valueOf(j), myTextArea.getText().lastIndexOf("\n"), myTextArea.getText().length());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Timer error!");
            }
        }
        return "Called!";

     }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you have a specifc problem?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want the bet to receive a default value if the user have not input a value after a certain amount of time?

Comment: @Ioannis Stefanou yes.

Comment: You can always simply use a javax.swing.Timer to achieve this. I can provide an example as an answer if you are interested to follow this approach.

Comment: @Ioannis Stefanou yes I'm interested to see your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a good approach here [closing-joptionpane-ShowInternalOptionDialog-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408528/closing-joptionpane-showinternaloptiondialog-programmatically)

Modifying for your case specifically:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {
    static String bet = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                pane.getRootFrame().dispose();

            }
        });
        t1.start();
        bet = pane.showInputDialog("give me a value");

        if(bet == null)
            bet = "30";


        System.out.println(bet);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

If the user gives no input, `JOptionPane` makes the `String bet = null`. So you check on that, and if the String is `null` you simply assign your own value to it.

Also, as I said in the comments, you can achieve the same thing with a `Timer`.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StackOverFlow {
    static String bet = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();

        Timer t = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ) {
                pane.getRootFrame().dispose();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        bet = pane.showInputDialog("give me a value");
        t.stop();

        if(bet == null) {
            bet = "30";
        }

        System.out.println(bet);
    }
}
```

Both ways achieve the same thing. The value 30 obviously can be given by a declared constant.