# How to use `doClick()` on JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a custom JOptionPane with two buttons as follows:

```
AgreementPanel panel = new AgreementPanel(this); // JPanel with some JLabels and JTextFields
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(panel, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
Object[] options = {"Accept", "Decline"};
option = pane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "Agreement", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, panel.txtMessage);
```

How can I use `doClick()` on `Accept` button? I need it somewhere in my program

Comment: Not sure for a JOptionPane, but it would be easy to do in a quickly built custom JDialog.

Comment: @Hovercraft an alternative solution could be with adding the two buttons to the JOptionPane, but another issue would appear which is when I press a button it won't close the JOptionPane, Is there a method to close the JOptionPane so I can add it the ActionListener of the buttons?

Comment: What happened?!!! all the comments and the answers are gone :\ ... however, @Hovercraft pane.setVisile(false) doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: [Closing a dialog created by JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730044/closing-a-dialog-created-by-joptionpane-showoptiondialog) :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing options as strings, you can directly pass jbuttons to the showOptionDialog() method. Internally it checks if its a button, then it directly adds it to the button area.

So do something like this:

```
JButton btnAccept = new JButton("Accept");
 Object[] options = {btnAccept , "Decline"};
btn.doClick();
```

Note that the BasicOptionPaneUI will take care of checking and adding the button rightly.

UPDATE: You can set the actionListener manually is the component is directly passed:

```
ActionListener al = ((BasicOptionPaneUI)optionPane.getUI()).new ButtonActionListener(1);
        btnAccept.setActionListener(al);
```

Comment: This works excpet it does not close the JOptionPane, I still to write a method to make it disposed or closed (`pane.setVisible(false)` does not work)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I have updated how to do add the right actionListener

Comment: still does not close the JOptionPane, also I need to add more code in the ActionListener beside closing the JOptionPane