# How to close JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have a JoptionPane like below. However, when I select a value and hit 'OK' it does return the value, but the frame still remains as is. Only after 'cancel' or 'X' mark on the top, it closes. How to fix this.

```
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                "Select the user",
                "Users",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                userNames,
                userNames[0]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing a dialog created by JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730044/closing-a-dialog-created-by-joptionpane-showoptiondialog)

Comment: What is `userNames`?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses